# Как выровнять блок по вертикали, если высота внешнего блока неизвестна?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, выравнивание

Есть верстка с хедером и мейном. Высота мейна заранее неизвестна, и вычисляется браузером на лету. Внутри мейна есть див. У дива заданы четкие размеры. Требуется выровнять див по вертикали, чтобы он был по середине мейна. Как это сделать?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 88px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(138, 138, 151);
}

main {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  background-color: rgb(221, 193, 67);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header></header>
  <main>
    <div class="content">контент для выравнивания</div>
  </main>
</div>
```

[image: Что я вижу в браузере]

**Результат, который я хочу получить:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: див классом контент выровнить надо?

Comment: @DeniDove да, относительно main

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
}

header {
  height: 88px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(138, 138, 151);
}

main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.content {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  background-color: rgb(221, 193, 67);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header></header>
    <main>
      <div class="content">контент для выравнивания</div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: это совсем не то, что я хочу сделать. Пожалуйста, внимательнее читайте вопрос.

Comment: Изменил, теперь всё как вы хотите

Comment: Так див выравнивается внутри body. А нужно выравнивать внутри main.

Comment: Ещё раз изменил, надеюсь так

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А так пробовали?

Добавьте эти свойства, А так пробовали? если правильно понял то так можно!!!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я вставил в вопрос скриншот результата, который я хочу получить. Еще раз перечитайте вопрос, и посмотрите скриншот с результатом.

Comment: @ОлегВерушкин моежт так? там еще марджин отрицательный сделаете если наполовину от размера блока, то прям ровно станет. марджин-топ: -половина его размера